# TypeError: (0 , redux_zero_1.default) is not a function

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I was getting the following error message when I tried to write unit tests for files that access the `redux-zero` store (just by importing the files, not even writing tests).

Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: (0 , redux_zero_1.default) is not a function

  1 | import createStore from 'redux-zero';
  2 | /** create redux-zero store */
> 3 | const store = createStore({
    |               ^
  4 |     appDimensions: {
  5 |         width: 0,
  6 |         height: 0

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/data/store.ts:3:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/remoteControl.ts:3:1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was importing `createStore` like this (and everything was working):

```
import createStore from "redux-zero";
```

However, this is how you should import it with TypeScript:

```
import * as createStore from "redux-zero";
```

It's documented here: https://github.com/redux-zero/redux-zero#how